# iAds not showing on developer device

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, iad

On the device I developed my app on, I saw the "test ad" screen on my app before I submitted to the app store. Then I deleted the version of my app that was installed by XCode and downloaded the app once it was approved by Apple via the App store. Now in my newly downloaded app, I STILL see the "test ad" banner. Is there any way to see the real banner on my development device? I am just curious what types of ads my users are seeing.

Comment: Have you tried removing your provisioning profiles from the device? This should both make sure you have the app store version and should also prevent anything from believing you're in a development environment

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the app and reinstalling it from XCode. That fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Mine fixed itself mysteriously but maybe this is actually what happened.

Comment: I also found a setting inside the settings app -> Development that allows you to control the rate at which test ads are served. That's worth checking if anybody else has a similar problem.